# Create a collection with product variants in shopify

Tags: collections, shopify, variants

Can I create a collection which contains specific product variants(Based on variant options).

Right now, our problem is that we can't add a variant to a collection, only a product.

The usecase is that we want to create a voucher code, which gives reduced prices for a specific variant of a product.

Comment: variants belong to products, you can not do that

Comment: Is there really no work-around? Being unable to create a discount for our digital variants(ePub) of our printed books seems like a major missing feature

Answer (score 0):

A book is a product. You can add products to collections. While it is true that a product has many variants, you cannot target a variant from a product, in a collection, unless you introduce your own very specific add hoc code. That would be fragile I bet. You could of course create a collection of products that all consisted of one variant, the digital version, eligible for a discount. Why is that such a big deal? The customer might find two products representing the same book, one digital and one not, but that should not pose much of an issue. In fact, a good designer will simply present both products on the same page, and let the customer choose the one they want. So you can indeed do what you want, provided you choose to learn how to setup that way.

Comment: Creating 3 versions of each book(We have: print/epub/pdf) is a big deal. Having all search results show up 3 times is a major deal(Maintaining product descriptions for over 300 products times 3 alone will kill that solution, and google would hate us if we did that). And having the customer click on the wrong "variant" of the product and then be unable to order the print version, because they somehow ended up on the pdf version would cause major problems. And we link directly to product pages which we can't do with each variant as a product, because then we would have to choose print/epub/pdf

Comment: Glass is half full for some, half empty for others. I was simply explaining how you could do it, and you think you have all these problems... well that is fine. Make one product then, with three variants, and just price the digital version cheaper. Holy crap what a crazy thing to do!!